# Split a column into multiple based on categories in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to split some data which is in excel, a sample of it is,

```
DATE        NAME    NUMBER
19700228    AERO    9
19700228    AGRIC   6
19700228    AUTOS   5
19700228    BANKS   10
19700228    BEER    10
19700228    BLDMT   7
19700228    BOOKS   3
19700228    BOXES   1
19700228    BUSSV   9
19700229    AERO    10
19700229    AGRIC   2
19700229    AUTOS   10
19700229    BANKS   5
19700229    BEER    9
19700229    BLDMT   3
19700229    BOOKS   7
19700229    BOXES   5
19700229    BUSSV   1
```

I would like each NAME to have its own column,

i.e. 
[image]

Is this possible in excel, also, each category could have different dates and I would need them to line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pivot table with the NAME field as the Columns and DATE as the Rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your first goto should definitely be a Pivot Table, explained by @StevenCarlson.

However, you could try this principle:

[image]

Formula `F1` and drag right:

```
{=INDEX($B$2:$B$19,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$B$2:$B$19),0))}
```

Formula `E2` and drag down:

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$A$19,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$19),0))}
```

Formula `F2` and drag down and right:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$19,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$19=$E2)*($B$2:$B$19=F$1)*ROW($A$2:$A$19)))
```

First two formulas are entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @JvdV great alternative method!